# Locking on spring mvc session command object

Tags: spring, session, model-view-controller, synchronization, locking

I hava a spring 4 mvc controller.  I am using annotations to handle multiple requests in the same controller. - e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/add_dob")
public String addDateOfBirth(.......) {
    ........
    validateDOB(form, result)
    ........
}

@RequestMapping("/add_address")
public String addAddress(.......) {
    ........
}
```

The thing is that I have a session command object (PERSON) and there is a possibility of the command object becoming inconsistent.  I tried using

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="synchronizeOnSession" value="true" />
</bean>
```

in the servlet-name.xml spring file but this is causing all requests on the application to be synchronized (I tested by putting Thread.sleep inside the request on which I intend to synchronize and then tried to access the home page).  Is there any way by which I can just synchronize on the session command object or on a scope smaller than the entire session?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specific session-scoped bean, e.g. Person:

```
<bean class="com.xyz.Person" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Or with annotations:

```
@Bean @Scope("session") @ScopedProxy class Person {...}
```

You can then @Autowire this bean to your web service class. Spring guarantees that any time you reference it you will receive the object from the current session. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) for more details.